# How to convert date format in R

Tags: r, date

My data contains a variable which recorded the date like "Wednesday 01/01/86". I want to drop the days like "Wednesday" and convert "01/01/86" into the format "1986-01-01".

I tried `as.Date(myData$DATE)` but I got an error message: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. I assume this is due to the character Wednesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `as.Date` what format your input is in:

```
as.Date("Wednesday 01/01/86", format="%A %m/%d/%y")
# "1986-01-01"
```

See docs for [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for more details.